# How/why does ssh output to tty when both stdout and stderr are redirected?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, redirection, pipe

I've just noticed that

```
ssh user@host >/tmp/out 2>/tmp/err
```

can write something like

```
Warning the RAS host key...
...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

stdout and stderr were both redirected but this still shows up in the tty.

1. How is `ssh` doing this?
2. Why is `ssh` doing this? Doesn't it violate *nix idioms?
3. When I am running `ssh` (or another program with similar behaviour) as a child process with stdin/stdout/stderr connected by pipes, I want the parent process to see the output from the child process. If the child process dodges stdout/stderr like this, how can the parent process capture it?

Comment: You may find [my previous analysis of sudo](https://serverfault.com/questions/731886/why-does-password-entering-work-in-a-piped-sudo-command/731943#731943) an interesting read. I suspect ssh does something similar: directly access the terminal via `/dev/tty` for prompts that should go to the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### How?

> How is `ssh` doing this?

It opens `/dev/tty`. The relevant line from `strace ssh …` is:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR)    = 4
```

The file descriptor `4` is then used with `write(2)` and `read(2)`.

<sup>(Testbed: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2).</sup>

---

#### Why?

> Why is `ssh` doing this? Doesn't it violate *nix idioms?

I'm not sure about "*nix idioms", whatever they are; but POSIX [explicitly allows this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html):

> `/dev/tty`
> In each process, a synonym for the controlling terminal associated with the process group of that process, if any. *It is useful for programs or shell procedures that wish to be sure of writing messages to or reading data from the terminal no matter how output has been redirected.* […]

<sup>(Emphasis mine).</sup>

Tools that need to *interact* with the user tend to use `/dev/tty` because it makes sense. Usually when users do this:

```
<local_file_0 ssh user@server tool >local_file_1 2>local_file_2
```

they want it to be as similar as possible to this:

```
<local_file_0 tool >local_file_1 2>local_file_2
```

The only difference should be where the `tool` actually runs. Usually users want `ssh` to be transparent. They don't want it to litter `local_file_1` or `local_file_2` and they don't want to wonder if they need to put `yes` or `no` in the `local_file_0` in case `ssh` asks. Often one cannot predict if `ssh` will ask in any particular case.

<sup>Note when you run `ssh user@server tool` there's a shell involved on the remote side (compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1546334/432690)). The shell can source some startup scripts that can litter the output. This is a *different* issue (and a reason the relevant startup scripts should be silent).</sup>

---

#### Solutions

> When I am running `ssh` (or another program with similar behaviour) as a child process with stdin/stdout/stderr connected by pipes, I want the parent process to see the output from the child process. If the child process dodges stdout/stderr like this, how can the parent process capture it?

As stated above, your wish is rather unusual. This doesn't mean it's weird or totally uncommon. There are usage cases where one really wants this. The solution is to provide a pseudo-terminal you can control. The right tool is [`expect(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). Not only it will provide a tty, but it will also allow you to implement some logic. You will be able to detect (and log) `Are you sure you want to continue connecting` and answer `yes` or `no`; or nothing if `ssh` doesn't ask.

If you want to capture the whole output while interacting normally then consider [`script(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script).

---

#### Broader picture

Up to this point we were interested in allocating tty on the client side, i.e. where `ssh` runs. In general you may want to run a tool that needs `/dev/tty` on the server side. The SSH server is able to allocate a pseudo-terminal or not, the relevant options are `-t` and `-T` (see `man 1 ssh`). E.g. if you do this:

```
ssh user@server 'sudo whatever'
```

then you will most likely see `sudo: no tty present …`. Provide a tty on the remote side and it will work:

```
ssh -t user@server 'sudo whatever'
```

But there's a quirk. Without `-t` the default stdin, stdout and stderr of the remote command are connected to the stdin, stdout and stderr of the local `ssh` process. This means you can tell apart the remote stdout from the remote stderr *locally*. With `-t` the default stdin, stdout and stderr (and `/dev/tty`) of the remote command point to the same pseudo-terminal; now stdout, stderr and whatever the remote command writes to its `/dev/tty` get combined into a *single* stream the local `ssh` prints to its (local) stdout. You cannot tell them apart locally. This command:

```
ssh -t user@server 'sudo whatever' >local_file_1
```

will write prompt(s) from `sudo` to the file! By using `/dev/tty` `sudo` itself tries to be transparent when it comes to redirections, but `ssh -t` sabotages this.

In this case it would be useful if `ssh` provided an option to allocate a pseudo-terminal (`/dev/tty`) on the remote side and to connect it to `/dev/tty` of the local `ssh`, *while still connecting the default remote stdin, stdout and stderr to their local counterparts*. Four separate channels (one of them bidirectional: `/dev/tty`).

AFAIK there is no such option (check this question and my answer there: [*`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618)). Currently you can have either three unidirectional channels (without `/dev/tty` for the remote process) or what appears as one bidirectional channel (`/dev/tty`) for the remote process and two unidirectional channels (stdin and stdout of the local `ssh`) for the local user.

Your original command:

> ```
> ssh user@host >/tmp/out 2>/tmp/err
> ```

does not specify a remote command, so it runs an interactive shell on the remote side and does provide a pseudo-terminal for it as if you used `-t` (unless there is no local terminal). This is the "one bidirectional channel for the remote process" case. It means that `/tmp/err` can only get stderr from the `ssh` itself (e.g. if you used `ssh -v`).

<sup>An *interactive* shell with output not being printed to the (local) terminal cannot be easily used interactively. I hope this was only a minimal example (if not then maybe you need to rethink this).</sup>

Anyway you can see a situation with `/dev/tty`, `ssh` and other tools that use `/dev/tty` can be complicated.

Comment: So how *do* you capture both stdout and sterr separately and still provide a password to sudo interactively? Hm. After thinking a bit, I guess `echo $password | ssh user@host cat \| sudo --prompt="" -S some_command.py > stdout.log 2> stderr.log` does the job …

Comment: I think that would be very useful! Your answer was extremely helpful, as I got confused trying to separately capture stdout and stderr from a command ran by sudo via SSH. (Edit: Whoops, your comment disappeared?)

Comment: @slhck I removed the comment because I decided by myself I'm going to publish. It will probably be a self-answered question on U&L. I will leave you a comment here with a link when it's ready. Should be in few days.

Comment: @slhck My self-answered question is here: [ssh with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618).