# Bash heredoc for passing multiple commands to a interactive command, script hangs after completion

Tags: bash

I am ssh-ing to a remote server to pass multiple commands to an interactive command

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@host << "EOF"
java -jar jmx.jar
--commands
quit
EOF

echo "finished"
```

jmx.jar opens up an new interactive terminal like mysql,sftp, etc.
The output from my commands is as i would expect, there is a response from my quit. But it just hangs after that and never reaches the "Finished"

Comment: Works for me (I replaced the java call with a simple script).

Comment: @choroba Your simple script was probably too simple. :) What the OP described can happen, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hypothesis

My guess is: something in your code spawns an asynchronous process that keeps its stdout connected to the SSH server; and the server is designed not to terminate the connection in such case.

---

#### Analysis

The SSH server like `sshd`, when it does not allocate a tty on the remote side (and you used `-T`, so this is the case), provides at least three separate data "pipes". Whatever your local `ssh` reads from its stdin will appear on the stdin of the shell spawned by the server (remote shell; there's always a shell); whatever that shell (or anything) prints to the stdout or stderr provided by the server will be printed by your local `ssh` to its stdout or stderr respectively.

In general processes spawned by a shell inherit stdin, stdout and stderr from it. This happens in the remote shell as well. This way you can do this:

```
<local_file_0 ssh user@server tool >local_file_1 2>local_file_2
```

and it will behave like this:

```
<local_file_0 tool >local_file_1 2>local_file_2
```

except the `tool` will run on the remote side (executed from a remote shell spawned by `sshd`). [This works even if `ssh` needs to ask for a password](https://superuser.com/q/1557557/432690) (but [there are more complex use cases when it's not enough](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618)).

Note if you use a here document (like you did, `<< "EOF"`), the document will "enter" the `ssh` via its stdin. Sometimes people expect the remote shell to read it all, and when anything else reads from its (inherited) stdin and consumes the shell code they are unpleasantly surprised. You deliberately rely on this behavior. The `java -jar jmx.jar` string is executed by the shell, but then `java` starts reading the stdin and the rest of your code is not shell code, it's something specific to `jmx.jar`. I'm mentioning this to show you your `java` inherits the standard descriptors exactly as stated above.

An asynchronous command (a command in the background) inherits the standard descriptors in the same way. The parent process may redirect some of them before spawning the child (e.g. in some circumstances shells redirect the stdin of an `asynchronous_command &` to `/dev/null`) or not.

**Now the main point:** if any remote process (in the background or not, irrelevant) still uses the stdout provided by the SSH server, the server keeps the connection open (at least `sshd` from OpenSSH does this) and your local `ssh` does not exit. I guess the server assumes that if anything keeps the stdout open then it may want to use it in the future and you (being on the local side) may want not to lose the output. This does not happen for stderr though.

In general the asynchronous process that keeps the connection open may be something you explicitly run in the background, or some (((…)great-)grand)child process of anything you run. In your case there's only `java`, so the troublesome process must be some descendant of it. There may be more than one troublesome process. Not knowing `--commands` I cannot tell what it (they) can be in your particular case.

---

#### Ideas

I'm not aware of any config option of `sshd` that would make it behave differently. I'm not aware of any config option one provides to `ssh` that would make the server behave differently, except `-t` or similar. Allocating a tty with `ssh -t` may not be a good idea (especially when using a here document). Without `ssh -t`, if you want `ssh` to exit when the remote shell exits, you need to make sure the processes left behind don't use the stdout connected to the SSH server process; this means you need to redirect their stdout away. Possibilities:

- Run programs that close their stdout when they know they are not going to use it anymore.
- Redirect stdout of the troublesome process to `/dev/null`. Obviously you will lose all standard output of the process.
- Redirect stdout of the troublesome process to a regular file on the remote side. (Note you may find a solution with `nohup`. In the context of our problem the important thing is `nohup` redirects the stdout (to `nohup.out` by default), but it's something you can do without `nohup`. I suspect all other features of `nohup` are irrelevant to the issue.)
- Redirect stdout of the troublesome process to its stderr (`>&2` operator in a shell). Locally you will see the output until `ssh` exits when you expected it to exit. The processes will get SIGPIPE when they try to write to a pipe that is no more (which may never happen); how a process reacts to SIGPIPE is up to the process itself. Also note that locally the redirected data will emerge from `ssh` via its stderr and you won't be able to tell it apart from anything that genuinely belongs to stderr.
- Redirect stdout of the troublesome process to a "relay", destroy the relay when you want `ssh` to exit. The point is to keep just one process (the relay) connected to the original stdout.

In general, as the troublesome process may be a remote descendant of something you explicitly run, it may not be easy (or possible at all) for you to redirect its stdout only. You may need to redirect stdout of the ancestor and this will affect the ancestor and all the offspring; this may be too much, especially when redirecting to `/dev/null`. Redirecting to a relay seems a good idea in general.

---

#### Examples

If my hypothesis is right then this will replicate the problem (you will see output from `date` printed after `DONE`):

```
ssh user@server '
  for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
    date; sleep 1
  done &
  sleep 3
  echo DONE
'
```

Redirecting the asynchronous subshell away from the original stdout will make `ssh` exit right after `DONE` is printed:

```
ssh user@server '
  for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
    date; sleep 1
  done >/dev/null &
  sleep 3
  echo DONE
'
```

Redirecting to stderr allows you to see the output until `DONE`:

```
ssh user@server '
  for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
    date; sleep 1
  done >&2 &
  sleep 3
  echo DONE
'
```

And this is a basic implementation of a relay. Ideally the code would start with `mktemp -d`, but let's keep our proof of concept relatively simple:

```
ssh user@server '
  tmpf=/tmp/fifo
  mkfifo "$tmpf"
  <"$tmpf" cat &
  relay="$!"
  trap "kill \"$relay\"" EXIT
  exec >"$tmpf"
  # from now on the cat is the only process that uses the original stdout
  # unlinking the fifo early is allowed, inheritance works via descriptors anyway
  rm "$tmpf"

  for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
    date; sleep 1
  done >&2 &
  sleep 3
  echo DONE
'
```

Note the trap may kill the `cat` even if in the pipe buffer there is unread data you *do* want to see. In my tests sometimes I see `DONE`, sometimes I don't, this is what I'm talking about. Delaying the `kill` (`trap "sleep 1; kill \"$relay\"" EXIT`) may mitigate the problem (and increase the probability of some output still being relayed *after* `DONE`!).

---

#### Your specific case

Maybe you will be able to identify the troublesome process(es) and change its behavior by modifying the `--commands` you pass to `java`. If you don't care about telling apart the remote stdout from stderr, `java -jar jmx.jar >&2` may be the only modification you need. Alternatively start with a relay: put `java …` in place of the `for … echo DONE` fragment in the last example above. Note `/tmp/fifo` in this simple example is hardcoded. For robustness, security, and/or if you want to run  multiple instances of the code, you should create a fifo in a private temporary directory each time (`mktemp -d`).