# Read from stdin while piping to next command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

How can you prompt a user for input, when the output is being piped?

```
> (echo -n 'input data: '; read TEST; export TEST) | echo "done: ${TEST}"
```

This does not show the "input data" prompt, and does not read anything from stdin, and instead, just displays:

```
done:
```

Comment: Why does the read need to be part of a pipeline?

Comment: Also, due to the parentheses the `read TEST` happens in a subshell, and due to the pipe the `echo "done: $TEST"` happens in a _different_ subshell -- two different variables!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `foo | bar` `foo` and `bar` run simultaneously. Your code displays `done:` because the final `echo` does not read its stdin and it does not wait for anything piped via its stdin. It does its job right away.

Additionally `${TEST}` after `|` has nothing to do with the variable your `read` sets before `|`. When building a pipeline, Bash runs each command in a separate subshell (the last one may or may not be executed in the context of the main shell).

This is what I think you want:

```bash
echo -n 'input data: '; read TEST
echo "done: ${TEST}"
```

(in Bash `read -p 'input data: ' TEST` will also work).

There is no need to pipe anything to anything here.

In general, in case you need to interact with the user from within a pipe (I mean from within a genuinely needed pipe), `/dev/tty` may be useful. Artificial example:

```
echo foo | ( read -p 'i: ' var </dev/tty; echo "d: $var" >/dev/tty; cat ) | nl
```

Here `read` does not read from the first `echo`, it reads form `/dev/tty`. Neither `read` nor the second `echo` prints to `nl`: `read -p` prints its prompt to stderr by default, `echo` prints to `/dev/tty` because we redirected. In effect the data (`foo`+newline) goes from `echo` to `cat` to `nl` as if nothing else was there.

It may look like a trick, but's it's a legitimate use case. E.g. see [*How/why does `ssh` output to tty when both stdout and stderr are redirected?*](https://superuser.com/q/1557557/432690) and [my answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1557724/432690).

Comment: or `read -p 'input data: ' TEST`

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you. My answer is now improved.