# How can I read input directly from the terminal instead of stdin

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell-script

**TLDR**; I want to read a user input directly from the terminal leaving stdin untouched.

#### context

I'm writing a shell script that handles user passwords (verifying strength and authenticating other apps).
Since the script also reads data from `stdin`, I can't simply use the good ol' one-liner solution.

```bash
read -s -p "Password: " password
```

If my script used the above method it wouldn't work correctly when the user pipes data to the script from another program.

Then I found out that `sudo` gets the user password from the terminal device directly, not interfering with `stdin`... unless told otherwise (with `-S` flag).

```
$ man sudo
...
     -S, --stdin
                 Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the stan‐
                 dard input instead of using the terminal device.

     -A, --askpass
                 Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's ter‐
                 minal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical)
                 helper program is executed to read the user's password and output the pass‐
                 word to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable is
                 set, it specifies the path to the helper program.
```

So that when I use `sudo some_priv_cmd` in the script, it can still prompt the user password even though `stdin` is occupied by some datastream.

#### question

I'm looking for a program that can prompt the user just like `sudo` does, and returns (or echoes) the input string. More specifically, the program can be used as `SUDO_ASKPASS`, and `sudo -A` should work just like normal `sudo`.

If such a utility does not exist, can someone provide some clues on how can I implement it? Which library, or function/feature should I be searching for?

#### my attempts

- I've tried `read -s -p` solution in place of `SUDO_ASKPASS` just to find the feature I'm looking for indeed requires special handling.
- I'm suspecting the `termios` library for dealing with terminal-specific tasks, but not sure how to use it.

Comment: See also: [*How/why does `ssh` output to tty when both stdout and stderr are redirected?*](https://superuser.com/q/1557557/432690) It's not a duplicate question, still my answer there contains a relevant citation and some insight.