# Looks like cron spawns a shell which in turn spawns a script; how can I get rid of the intermediate shell?

Tags: linux, script, cron, sh

The OS is CentOS 7.

I have a rather basic understanding of crontab and crond. I created a crontab entry using `crontab -e`:

```
*/5 * * * * /root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The script detects if run more than once using a `.pid` file and exits, so only a single instance will keep running at any given time. If no error occurs, the script is intended to keep running forever (until shutdown/reboot). On startup, the cron will invoke the script.

The thing I can't understand is two processes are spawned. This isn't a case of crond running twice. The commandlines are different. One starts with `sh` and the other starts with the script itself. After they start, I can kill the `sh` process without any adverse effects, but if I don't kill it it looks like it's going to run as long as the script is running. I'd like to avoid continuously running two processes, if one would do the job adequately. What am I doing wrong?

Others must have encountered this issue before, but I couldn't figure out how to phrase a google search. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note: a single instance of a script running forever can be implemented as a systemd service. There's nothing particularly wrong with the cron-based approach though. If it fits your needs then keep it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing. What you are doing is not wrong, it is at most sub-optimal. The described situation is normal. It can be optimized though. Keep reading.

---

#### Preliminary note

There are different implementations of cron and different implementations of `sh`. I could run a scratch CentOS 7 and pretty accurately deduce your cron and your `sh` from it, I think. But I won't. This answer is going to be more generic. Therefore don't be surprised if I write something like "`sh` could do this and this, but apparently your `sh` doesn't".

---

#### Analysis

When the time comes your cron runs `/bin/sh` (or [another shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94459/108618)) and passes the `/root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` string as an option-argument for `-c`. So it's like

```
/bin/sh -c '/root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

except the above line is what you would type in a shell, while cron builds (or at least should build) the argument array directly, where `/bin/sh`, `-c` and `/root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` are separate elements and there is no need for additional single-quotes (so you can use single-quotes in the command and they will not break anything).

There is at least one thing cron does to the specified command prior to passing it to `sh`: it interprets `%` (see `man 5 crontab`). Your command does not contain `%`, so this mechanism is not relevant. Cron could do more:

- It could detect `$`, `|`, `&&`, `;` and such and decide it should certainly run a shell that will handle these.
- In your case it could detect the shell would not be needed, if only cron itself handled the redirections; so it would handle the redirections and run `/root/script.sh` directly.
- It could detect really simple commands (e.g. `/usr/bin/beep`) and run them directly.

It could but [it shouldn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well). It's not its job to optimize and act like a shell. Its job is to run a command interpreter (shell) which takes it from here.

In your case `sh` is spawned. It interprets `/root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1`, handles the redirections and runs `/root/script.sh` as a child process.

In general a shell can optimize this step, your `sh` apparently doesn't. Some shells do. It's possible for a shell to reliably tell if it can "disappear". I will elaborate below.

---

#### Solutions

1. (inferior) Run the command asynchronously. If your command is

   ```
   /root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
   ```

   then cron will run `sh` and the `sh` will exit without waiting for `script.sh` to finish. This has side effects though:

   - cron will see its child process (i.e. `sh`) exited. There will be no direct connection between cron and the `script.sh` process ([unless cron sets itself up as a "subreaper"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/108618), your cron probably doesn't).
   - cron will see its child process (i.e. `sh`) exited with exit status `0`. Normally (without `&`) the exit status of `sh` would depend on the exit status of `script.sh`; but for this to happen `sh` must wait for `script.sh` to finish.

   By manually killing `sh` you inadvertently introduced these side effects. In particular cron doesn't care much, I think (it can be configured to log failed jobs though). But in general the parent process may care, so users should not "randomly" kill intermediate shells; and shells should not arbitrarily decide they can exit without waiting for the last command. As far as I know no shell does this kind of "optimization".
2. **(suprior) Explicitly `exec` to `script.sh`**:

   ```
   exec /root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
   ```

   [`exec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec) makes the shell replace itself with the command without creating a new process. In this case `script.sh` will replace `sh` under the same process ID. In the context of the side effects mentioned above, this is very nice:

   - The parent process won't notice when `sh` "disappears". It will see `script.sh` instead of `sh`; and it will consider `script.sh` the child. Without `exec` the parent process would be notified when its child (`sh`) exits just after `script.sh` exits. With `exec` the parent process will be notified when `script.sh` exits, because this is the child now. Effectively in both cases it's when `script.sh` exits.
   - The parent process will get the exit status directly from `script.sh` when it terminates. The fact `sh` no longer exists is irrelevant. Without `exec` the parent process would get the exit status relayed by `sh` from the last command it runs, i.e. from `script.sh`. Effectively in both cases it's the exit status from `script.sh`.

   This method is almost transparent, even if the parent process cares about when the child exits or what exit status it returns. This is the optimization shells can do. Bash does it. In some cases it may be quite confusing if you don't know about it; compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1546334/432690) where there is `sshd` instead of cron.

   If you [tell cron to use `bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94459/108618) and you don't use `exec` then the optimization may kick in, as if you used `exec`; or it may not, it depends on the command. So if you want the shell to `exec` for sure then explicitly tell it to `exec`; do not rely on optimization capabilities of the shell.

   Now your cron uses `sh` which most likely never optimizes like this, so use `exec` explicitly in the command.

   Side note: `exec command1; command2` or `exec command1 && command2` will never get to `command2`. Keep this in mind, especially if you happen to have `exec command1` and decide to add `command2` to the job. These should work: `command1; exec command2` or `command1 && exec command2`. But then expect `sh` process to exist when `command1` runs; you need it to run `command2` later.

Comment: Did you mean `/bin/sh -c '/root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1' /bin/sh` in the first code block? The following text would imply yes... but what's the purpose of the second / last `/bin/sh`?

Comment: @Attie I removed the second `/bin/sh` because cron (at least in my Debian) doesn't use this argument. In this case it doesn't matter. In case there are more arguments, [it does](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690).

Comment: Ah, I wondered if it was something like that... thanks for the link!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it.